# Right align button in frame

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How do we right align a button in a Progress ABL frame?

Here's a part of my code:

```
DEFINE BUTTON make-btn LABEL "save". //left of the frame
DEFINE BUTTON cancel-btn LABEL "cancel". //right of the frame
```

I need both buttons on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using the FRAME phrase and doing absolute positions. You can also use a more dynamic way (I've commented out an example). There's most likely several ways of doing this. Hope this version can get you started at least.

Check out FRAME and FORM statements in the documentation. You can find documentation for your version [here](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview). The ABL Reference is where you should start.

Links to documentation (Version 11.6) :

- [DEFINE FRAME](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge116/openedge116/#page/dvref/define-frame-statement.html#)
- [FORM statement](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge116/openedge116/#page/dvref/form-statement.html#)

Example program:

```
DEFINE BUTTON make-btn   LABEL "save" .
DEFINE BUTTON cancel-btn LABEL "cancel" .

DEFINE VARIABLE value1 AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO LABEL "Value1".
DEFINE VARIABLE value2 AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO LABEL "Value2".
DEFINE VARIABLE value3 AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO LABEL "Value3".



DEFINE FRAME frame-buttons
    value1 SKIP
    value2 SKIP
    value3 SKIP
    make-btn   AT COLUMN 4  ROW 8 
    cancel-btn AT COLUMN 40 ROW 8
    WITH 2 COLUMNS TITLE "Test" SIZE 50 BY 10.

/*
/*Dynamic positioning example */
cancel-btn:COLUMN = FRAME frame-buttons:WIDTH - 10.
*/
VIEW FRAME frame-buttons .

ENABLE ALL WITH FRAME frame-buttons.

UPDATE value1 WITH FRAME frame-buttons.
```

Comment: can you post a better link or delete that link?

Comment: What's wrong with the link? That's the general link to all versions. If you tell me what version you're on I can pinpoint that documentation set.

Comment: the link is as you link to google doesn't help , link to reference to frame and form

Comment: I'm not linking to Google. I'm linking to the official documentation collection. I've tested the link. I'm adding links to FRAME and FORM specifications of the latest version.